# Non Integer breaking Integer input

Tags: python

When i  enter a non number in this code it breaks with this message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Default/Desktop/AS91076.py", line 12, in 
>       temp = int(input("At what Temperature do you want your wash? (Maximum 40 Degrees)"))
>   ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asdf'

```
        temp = int(input("At what Temperature do you want your wash? (Maximum 40 Degrees)"))
        if temp < 41:
        **Misc Code**
        else:
            print("Not a valid Temperature!")
```

Comment: try typing `40` instead of `'asdf'` and google `if isinstance(temp, int): # do something`

Comment: @SteveSmith the file name suggests it's Python

Comment: Reading between the lines - I believe what you want is covered by the linked duplicate

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane `isinstance('123', int)` returns `False`

Comment: yeah very true. I'm going to grab a coffee lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arbitrary string can not be converted to a number. If you want to catch cases when the user types a non-integer, you can use the `try` statement.

```
try:
    temp = int(input("At what Temperature do you want your wash? (Maximum 40 Degrees)"))
    if temp < 41:
        **Misc Code**
    else:
        print("Temperature too high!")
 except ValueError as e:
        print("Not a valid Temperature!")
```